# The basis for the row space for a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As far as I have learned, to determine the row space of a matrix, we just need to reduce it to a RREF of the matrix, and the non-zero rows are the basis for the row space. So we can choose from the corresponding original matrix row as the basis. But look at this case:

\begin{bmatrix}
 2&  -2& 4 & -2\\ 
 -3&  3&  -6& 3\\ 
 6&  -3& 9 & -3\\ 
 2&  -3& 5 & -4\\ 
 5&  -4& 9 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
Applying scaling to first and third row, and row replacements to the rest, we have
\begin{bmatrix}
 1&  -1& 2 & -1\\ 
 0&  0&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  1& -1 & 3\\ 
 0&  -1& 1 & -2\\ 
 0&  1& -1 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
So, we are down to just reducing the bottom three rows.

We can see that the bottom three rows are only going to produce two pivots, since the second and third column value are all the same / negative multiple.

But here's the thing. Essentially, it is entirely up to us which row gets reduced, and which one gets preserved.
For example, I can keep the third row, $\begin{bmatrix}0&1&-1&3\end{bmatrix}$, and reduce the fourth and fifth rows. Or I can choose to keep the fifth row, $\begin{bmatrix}0&-1&-1&6\end{bmatrix}$, and reduce the third and the fourth, and do an interchange between fifth and third. This way, there are multiple rows that can become pivot rows. This will affect on the basis that we choose from the original matrix; it can include $\begin{bmatrix}6&-3&9&-3\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}2&-3&5&-4\end{bmatrix}$, or $\begin{bmatrix}5&-4&9&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}2&-3&5&-4\end{bmatrix}$.

If we just take from the rows of RREF then there would be no problem. But if it's from the original matrix, how do I resolve this?

Comment: You dont chose from the original matrix. That is for getting a column basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basis $\mathcal{B}$ for a vector (sub-)space $V$ is simply an ordered list of vectors $\mathcal{B} = \left\{ \vec{b_1}, \vec{b_2}, \dots, \vec{b_n} \right\}$ such that:

1. The basis vectors are *linearly independent*
2. The basis vectors *span* the entire vector (sub-)space $V$

That's it! For any non-trivial vector space, there are *infinitely many* possible bases you could choose. Beyond that, it is simply a question of aesthetics (some may be easier to work with than others). You should convince yourself that the different bases you are considering span the exact same vector sub-space (which happens to be the row space). They are all equally valid choices--the only unique thing is that any basis you choose will have exactly the same number of vectors, which we call the dimension.

In some cosmic sense, a choice of basis corresponds to choosing a coordinate system with which to study things. Just as we can pick any reasonable coordinate system, we are free to choose whatever basis we like--so long as it is, in fact, a coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

You are free to operate on the rows as you prefer, you can certainly get different basis but the choice will not affect the row space.

Comment: So you mean there are more than one correct solution based on the original matrix?

Comment: Yes there are infinite basis, operating by rows combination you preserve row space and find one of the basis.